# Ruby: How do you escape from a regex with ']'

Tags: ruby, regex, string, warnings

So I'm new to regex and I keep getting this warning and I don't know how to correct it:

```
madlib.rb:4: warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /\[(\w*:*\w)]/
```

From this code:

```
keys=Hash.new { |h, k|
   puts "Give me #{k.sub(/\[(\w*:*\w)]/, "")}:"
   h[$1]=$stdin.gets.chomp

}
print keys
puts "", $*[0].split(".")[0].gsub("_", " "),
     IO.read($*[0]).gsub(/\[(\w*:*\w)]/) { keys[$1] }
```

They way I call it seems simple at the moment, in the terminal I just put `madlib.rb Story1.txt`, but i'm going to be trying to implement it in a webpage using erb and sinatra, but I rather not have these warning pop up if I can help it.

Comment: The warning specifically says what the problem is. Did you try escaping `]` to see what'd happen?

Comment: In this context "escaping" means adding a backslash.

Comment: I did, just not in the right spot, then to many...

Comment: How could you know how to escape `[` but not how to escape `]` the same way?

Comment: As stated new to regex, also been rushed so I missed so many of the simple things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\`.

```
/\[(\w*:*\w)\]/
```

That should fix the issue

Comment: Thanks, I almost had it I just put the \ in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the backslash.

```
keys=Hash.new { |h, k|
   puts "Give me #{k.sub(/\[(\w*:*\w)\]/, "")}:"
   h[$1]=$stdin.gets.chomp

}
print keys
puts "", $*[0].split(".")[0].gsub("_", " "),
     IO.read($*[0]).gsub(/\[(\w*:*\w)\]/) { keys[$1] }
```